# How to skip an IP when using Nmap in Python?

Tags: python, try-catch, nmap, network-scan

I am using nmap in python, and trying to scan the network using a text file. All the scan ranges are in a text file, like so:

192.168.1.1-100
192.168.1.120-200
...

Though, lets say if the scan did not find host 192.168.1.3, because it was offline. The program will crash. Is there a way that I can get around this crashing? Can I use something like Try / Catch?

---

```
counter = 0
with open('range.txt') as rangefile:
    content = rangefile.readlines()

while counter < len(content):
    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
    #define the nmap scan here
    nm.scan(content[counter], '517', '-sU -sT')
```

This is the sample of code

```
  File "c:\...\nmapscan.py", line 63, in <module> therehost = Host.objects.get(ipv4_address=hosts) va.assessment.models.DoesNotExist: Host matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'ipv4_address': u'134.250.16.103'}
```

This is the error

Comment: How does it crash?  Does it give a traceback?  If yes, then you can try/except that exception.  Have you considered subprocess.Popen instead of an nmap module?  What module are you using, if any?  Note that if you catch the exception (assuming there is one), you may find that the rest of the scan is not completed.  subprocess.Popen would be almost just like running nmap at the command line.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the crash information or errors? What nmap options are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nmap` takes two arguments for exclusion. `--exclude` takes host name(s) and `--excludefile` takes a file containing name of hosts that need to be excluded. Use one of these as your need.
For more on setting target see the [man](http://nmap.org/book/man-target-specification.html) page.

Here is my test result -

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, May  3 2012, 15:54:42) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nmap
>>> nm=nmap.PortScanner()
>>> nm.scan('134.250.16.103','517', '-sU -sT')
{'nmap': {'scanstats': {'uphosts': '0', 'timestr': 'Sat Jul 28 12:54:27 2012', 'downhosts': '1', 'totalhosts': '1', 'elapsed': '3.06'}, 'scaninfo': {'udp': {'services': '517', 'method': 'udp'}, 'tcp': {'services': '517', 'method': 'connect'}}, 'command_line': 'nmap -oX - -p 517 -sU -sT 134.250.16.103'}, 'scan': {'134.250.16.103': {'status': {'state': 'down', 'reason': 'no-response'}, 'hostname': ''}}}
>>>
```

You can use try-catch-

```
try:
   nm.scan(content[counter], '517', '-sU -sT')
except:
   #handle exception...
```

As you don't which servers are down, you can ping the server before you proceed to nmap scan.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply! Though, when using nmap in python, you have to import nmap, and use commands like nm.PortScanner(). I don't think the nmap library has methods to read files.

Comment: nmap in python is just the implementation of `nmap` in python. it executes `nmap` command that you use in a terminal using `subprocess.Popen()`. so if python-nmap does fulfill your need, why you are not implementing `nmap` by yourself?

Comment: with open('range.txt') as rangefile:
    content = rangefile.readlines()
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
counter = 0

while counter < len(content):
    nm.scan(content[counter], '517', '-sU -sT ')

This is what I am using, and if an IP does not exist, it will error out. Can I  use Try and Exception to handle this? And if so, how?

Comment: which version of 'python-nmap' are using? I've tested on linux using python-nmap 0.2.4. it was pretty successful.